# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet success fully received from the server was 176,705,355 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 176,705,366 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

I am getting above exception when ever insert query in log4j.xml gets executed??

Comment: The error seems self-explanatory. What's your question?

Comment: how to solve this problem ??

Comment: i am getting this exception when ever i log some operation in my web application

Comment: " You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem."

Comment: even after increasing wait-timeout in mysql , i get this exception in production server